# How to use CURL/CygWin to send files from local Windows machine to Server?

Tags: curl, cygwin, couchdb

My goal is to upload a CouchDB document from my Windows machine to a remote server using cygwin/curl.

Here is a tutorial that shows how to do the same on a Mac:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-couchdb/

> curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/mycouchshop/ -d @person.json -H "Content-Type: application/json

How can I do the same with Windows & CygWin?

Comment: exactly the same way? what problem are you having trying to run that?

Comment: The example I found (url above) says to "open the terminal and execute cd ~/Desktop/". When I enter that into cygwin I get:  "No such file or directory". The file I would like to send is in my Libraries folder.

Comment: just `cd` to wherever you want the data stored.

Comment: How? What should I enter? CD ___ ? I am new to the command line.

Comment: btw, whatever I try to cd into always gives me the message "No Such File or Directory"

Comment: Ok, figured out how to cd in. First: cd ../    .... then: cd /cygdrive/c/Users/[put user name here]/Documents/[more directories here]/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After opening cygwin.

**step 1** - CD into the directory that contains the file you would like to post via CURL:

```
cd ../
cd /cygdrive/c/Users/[put user name here]/Documents/[more directories here]/
```

*Note: The strange part is having to go through the "cygdrive" directory.*

**step 2** - Use CURL to send the file:

`curl -X POST http://mywebsite.com/path/to/directory -d @some_file.extension -H "Content-Type: application/json"`

Replace "mywebsite.com...", "some_file.extension" and "application/json" with actual values.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you got it. Also on Windows, the single-quote (`'`) is not allowed. Use double-quote for your JSON data and then use `\"` for double-quotes *inside* the JSON.

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:5984/db/doc -d "{\"like\": \"this\"}"
```