# How can i automate a file upload from my computer to my apache web server with out using a web browser.

Tags: php, apache, scheduled-tasks

I am using php as programming language an apache is my web server . I am getting a log file from a bio-metric device. I need to upload the file to my web application two times in a day. My parser in my web application will do database insertions. Now one person is uploading the file manually through web browser. It would be great if someone suggest a method to automate the activity using a scheduler. My client machine is running on windows.

Comment: [`How to use CURL/CygWin to send files from local Windows machine to Server?`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005687/how-to-use-curl-cygwin-to-send-files-from-local-windows-machine-to-server) Possibly.

Comment: Or even [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1894479/2518525). (*Hard to say how to help without knowing how you'd like to send the file to the server*)